# Is the output content of the debug filter related to the output time

Tags: vscode-debugger

if debug output in same time, debug filter can't filter anything. why and how to fix this.
thanks for your help
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvOJH.png)

[not same time, it's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dAiR.png)